# Optimized method to check if an integer lies in the given range/bounds check

Tags: c, linux

In c programming to find if any given value lies between the range, `if` condition is used as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define U_LIMIT     100
#define L_LIMIT    -100

int check_num(char *in)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (in[i] == '-' || in[i] == '+') {
        i++;
        if (in[i] == '\0')
            return 0;
    }

    while (i < strlen(in)) {
        if(!isdigit(in[i]))
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    if (argc != 2)
       return 1;

    if (!check_num(argv[1])) {
       printf("Not a digit\n");
       return 1;
    }

    i = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (i < U_LIMIT && i > L_LIMIT)
       printf("Within Range\n");
    else
       printf("Outside Range\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
./a.out 1    -> Within Range
./a.out 100  -> Outside Range
./a.out -100 -> Outside Range
./a.out -    -> Not a digit
./a.out e    -> Not a digit
```

My question is that

> 1. Can the above program be optimized(for speed) further without loosing out any of the error check conditions?
> 2. Is there any other best optimized(for speed) method to solve for the same issue?

Comment: You should not care about the `if` test (which is always the fastest way to check for being inside some fixed interval): your program runs very quickly and most of the time is spent elsewhere.

Comment: Remember: [**premature optimization is the root of all evil**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart. Thanks. That was helpful. Will definitely consider that.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to check the user input, and then parse it. Just use [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) to accomplish both at once:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define U_LIMIT     100
#define L_LIMIT    -100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Missing argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* ALWAYS check the return value from scanf() and friends!
     * It returns the number of items in your format string successfully
     * assigned to. Make sure it matches the number of values you're
     * expecting, (one in this case).
     */
    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &i) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid number\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Doesn't get any simpler than an if statement */
    if (i < U_LIMIT && i > L_LIMIT)
       printf("Within Range\n");
    else
       printf("Outside Range\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Also, don't try to do crazy optimizations this early in the game. Focus on writing clean, concise code, and let the optimizing compiler take care of the rest for you.

At `-O3` optimization level, GCC produces the following assembly for `main()`. I kept just the interesting part about the integer comparison.

GCC command line: `gcc -Wall -Werror -O3 -g test.c`

Objdump command line: `objdump -d -Mintel -S a.out`

```
if (i < U_LIMIT && i > L_LIMIT)
  4004e5:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp]
  4004e8:   add    eax,0x63
  4004eb:   cmp    eax,0xc6
  4004f0:   jbe    400500 <main+0x50>
```

Note what the compiler did for you. Instead of making two comparisons, it first added 0x63 (99) to `i`, then, compared that value to 0xC6 (198). This is equivalent to something like:

```
if ((unsigned int)(i + 99) <= 198)
```

This way, only one conditional branch was necessary. The cool part is that it does an unsigned comparison. If `i` was less than -100, then `(i + 99)` would still be negative, and interpreted as an unsigned integer is 0xfffffed3 (a really big number) which is *not* <= 198.

And the best part? You didn't even need to think about it!

Comment: Answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (i < strlen(in))
```

Since your question asks about time optimization then here is a part which you improve on

```
int n =strlen(in);

while(i<n){
```

by doing this `strlen()` is not calculated in each iteration which is time consuming. Rest of the code should be fine as you are using `if()` to check the bounds which is simpler and best.

Comment: Answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Option strtol()**

You might want to use just `strtol(3)`:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);

The strtol() function converts the initial part of the string in 
nptr to a long integer value according to the given base, which 
must be between 2 and 36 inclusive, or be the special value 0.
```

Furthermore: you will get a return value if the input data overflows or underflows.

Furthermore: the function will place the `endptr` to the first 'invalid' character.

```
char*     in = "123a";
size_t   len = strlen(in);
char*    end = NULL;
long int out = strtol(in, &end, 10);

if (out == LONG_MIN || out == LONG_MAX) {
    // underflow || overflow
} else if (in + len < end) {
    // invalid chars while parsing
} else {
    // ok
}
```

**Option sscanf()**

The standard alternative is to use `sscanf()` which is ok in general but might be a bottleneck when you need to parse A LOT of integers (reparsing the format-string is an issue).

**Option rollyourown()**

Since you roll your own check already you might as well do the parsing yourself (taken from scan_ulong.c of qmail):

```
unsigned int scan_ulong(const char *s, unsigned long *u) {
    unsigned int pos = 0;
    unsigned long result = 0;
    unsigned long c;
    while ((c = (unsigned long) (unsigned char) (s[pos] - '0')) < 10) {
        result = result * 10 + c;
        ++pos;
    }

    if (u) {
        *u = result;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

This piece is the equivalent of your `isdigit()` code but also parses the number at the same time. If parsing numbers is a speed issue for your project, consider option `strtol()` (depends a bit on which compiler / platform you use) or the `scan_ulong()` variant, otherwise just stick with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Answer was helpful. Thank you.